# Как правильно настроить домен?

Tags: apache, dns, ubuntu

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать задачу.

На компьютер установил VMware, создал виртуальную машину, на которую установил ubuntu, apache, на виртуалке у меня два сайта: site.zo и mywork.zo.

Как сделать, чтобы при вводе в браузере site.zo и mywork.zo открывались сайты, расположенные на виртуальной машине?

Сейчас я прописываю у себя на винде в файле hosts - всё работает, но такой вариант меня не устраивает.

Comment: Вам нужно так или иначе обыграть обычный DNS и предоставить на выбранные сайты свой. Если у вас не стоит роутера, который такое умеет, то редактирование hosts останется самым простым методом.

Comment: Дело в том, что я создал вторую виртуалку, и мне нужно, чтоб я мог с этой виртуалки обращаться к другой не по ip, а по домену.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в /etc/hosts на каждом хосте ваши сайты. Либо установите bind и настройте зону "zo", добавив А-записи для ваших сайтов в dns. Настроить bind для такой конфигурации не сложно. В случае если выберете второй вариант, не забудтьте указать в качестве dns сервера на тестовых хостах, ваш виртуальный сервер с bind.

Comment: Спасибо попробую ваш вариант.

Comment: Советую dnsmasq, он проще в настройке для таких целей